# Loop through images in HTML with a timer

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

This is my code, it only outputs the original red image and i don't     understand how i'm supposed to make the code able to loop. Could someone help as     I need this code desperately?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1> The traffic script</h1>
<script>


var list = [
    "H:/GCSE COMPUTING/a452/traffic thingy/traffic/bleh/red.jpg",
    "H:/GCSE COMPUTING/a452/traffic thingy/traffic/bleh/amber.jpg",
    "H:/GCSE COMPUTING/a452/traffic thingy/traffic/bleh/green.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == list.length) index = 0;
    var image = document.getElementById('red');
    image.src=list[index];
}
window.onload = changelights;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img id="red" src="H:/GCSE COMPUTING/a452/traffic     thingy/traffic/bleh/red.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetInterval - this is not a loop like a for loop, etc. It is simply a block of code that will get triggered every x miliseconds.

```
var list = [
    "H:/GCSE COMPUTING/a452/traffic thingy/traffic/bleh/red.jpg",
    "H:/GCSE COMPUTING/a452/traffic thingy/traffic/bleh/amber.jpg",
    "H:/GCSE COMPUTING/a452/traffic thingy/traffic/bleh/green.jpg"
];


   var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == list.length) index = 0;
    var image = document.getElementById('red');
    image.src=list[index];
}
setInterval(function(){changeLights()}, 4000);
```

This will call changeLights every 4 seconds. Also - be careful asking GCSE questions here especially the course work.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a built-in interval method, which can be used as a loop in this case.

```js
var backgroundInterval = setInterval(function() {
    changeLights();

    if(index == (list.length - 1)) {
        clearInterval(backgroundInterval); // stop the loop when it hits last image
    }
}, 4000); // every 4000 ms, or 4s
```